# how to add multiple images into firebase database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

How can I add multiple images into Firebase Realtime Database

## My Code

```
private void uploadProductToFirebase() {

        final StorageReference imageFilePath = ProductImagesRef;

        for (int uploadCount = 0; uploadCount<ImageList.size(); uploadCount++){
            Uri IndividualImage= ImageList.get(uploadCount);
            final StorageReference ImageName = imageFilePath.child(pname);
            final int finalUploadCount = uploadCount;
            ImageName.putFile(IndividualImage).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    ImageName.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                            String url = String.valueOf(uri);
                            DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("ProductImages").child(productkey);
                            Product product = new Product();
                            if (finalUploadCount == 0){
                                product.setImage1(url);
                            }
                            else if (finalUploadCount == 1){
                                product.setImage2(url);
                            }
                            else if (finalUploadCount == 2){
                                product.setImage3(url);
                            }
                            databaseReference.setValue(product);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

If i add these three images only the 3rd image is stored into database.

What should I change to be able to upload 3 images to the Firebase Storage and Firebase RealTime Database?

Comment: Actually it over writes the previous one as your `imageFilePath` remains same. Can you explain what do you want?

Comment: i want all three images to be uploaded to firebase realtime database

Answer (score 0):

## Suggestion

I would test the following code to see if the problem is with your Product class.

```
String url = String.valueOf(uri);
DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("ProductImages").child("1234");
Product product = new Product();
if (finalUploadCount == 0){
 databaseReference.child("image_1").setValue(url);
}
else if (finalUploadCount == 1){
   databaseReference.child("image_2").setValue(url);
}
else if (finalUploadCount == 2){
   databaseReference.child("image_3").setValue(url);
}
```

Your might be only saving the last Firebase Storage. Check the Firebase Storage is creating the image, if it is this might be a problem on the line:

```
 databaseReference.setValue(product);
```

Also, there is a working example that I implemented in Kotlin.

It gets some image from the user gallery and upload to Firebase Storage, after that it stores the Firebase Storage Reference to my Realtime Database.

So my advice is for you to try to work with Bitmap, then do a task for upload it to Firebase Storage. You might consider to compress your image before uploading to not consume all your storage space (It might get expensive if you don't do that)

## Kotlin Example

```
private fun handleImageUpload() {
        val filePath : StorageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference.child("user_image").child(mAuth.currentUser!!.uid)

        var  bitmap: Bitmap? = null

        try {
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(application.contentResolver, resultUri)
        } catch (e : IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }

        val boas = ByteArrayOutputStream()
        bitmap!!.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 20, boas)
        val data = boas.toByteArray()
        val uploadTask = filePath.putBytes(data)

        uploadTask.continueWithTask { task ->
            if (!task.isSuccessful) {
                task.exception?.let {
                    throw it
                }
            }
            filePath.downloadUrl
        }.addOnCompleteListener { task ->
            if (task.isSuccessful) {
                val downloadUri = task.result
                val newImage = HashMap<String, Any>()
                newImage.put("profileImageUrl", downloadUri.toString())
                mCustomerDatabase.updateChildren(newImage)
            } else {
                // Handle failures
                // ...
            }
        }
    }
```

## Java Example

https://github.com/jirawatee/FirebaseStorage-Android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/storage/UploadActivity.java

Comment: can you provide a more assertivein which part did not work? Did you try the code I mention?